# Hidden screen in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, screen

This looks like a simple problem, but I don't know why I'm not able to find the solution. Maybe because I don't know how to express the question.

It feels like there's a screen extension beyond my monitor and sometimes some windows are going into that space and I'm not able to access those windows unless I restart my computer. I can see that part of the screen when I take screenshot(though I didn't check when the window disappeared, I don't want that to happen again or wait for it to happen[image]).

I've added the picture, can anyone tell me how to disable or remove this extra screen. I've used unity in 16.04 until recently...

Comment: I use Xfce4 (Xubuntu), not Unity, but I control screens with the _Display_ setting, in Xubuntu is easy to find. If you find such settings, do any other Displays appear there? Could you disable them there? Have you installed any Additional Graphic Driver that is not functioning well? If so remove it and see if there is any difference. Weird problem...

Comment: @vasilis74 when I was using older version of Ubuntu, I remember having unknown display, but now it's a bit new, and there are few options like mirror display, etc in display settings, I don't know what each does, so I didn't want to mess up the display I already had. I also installed a couple of extensions earlier and mouse click stopped working, so I reinstalled Ubuntu, but the screen is same...

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simple, I just selected the single display option in among the three display options in display settings in devices. Though I was worried what's unknown display in each setting, I tried selecting that too and the screen went blank, but the changes revert back if we don't confirm, so I know we shouldn't select that option in single display. I think the other two can be selected when there's another display device attached, don't know why it was selected by default.